# What are some secondary texts, in the form of online articles, to read about Kant's Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics?

Tags: kant

What are some secondary texts, in the form of online articles, to read about Kant's *Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics* before I jump into the text and to ease myself into understanding it?

It would be preferable these web articles were written by Kant scholars and could be finished in around ~15 minutes.

---

I'm using the translation by Paul Carus as the *Prolegomena*, if that is of any relevance.

This is the version:--

([https://www.amazon.com/Kants-Prolegomena-any-Future-Metaphysics-ebook/dp/B004UO69DE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1525052190&sr=8-1&keywords=1420938266](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UO69DE))

Citation for the link above:--

> Kant, Immanuel. Kant's Prolegomena to any future metaphysics. No. 53. Open court publishing Company, 1912.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Not an article but there's a YouTube talk on the Prolegomena which might get you launched :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEAqr_8PJqI

2) http://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/prolegomena/section4/

It is worth a browse.

3) https://www.gradesaver.com/prolegomena-to-any-future-metaphysics/study-guide/summary-preamble

It is pretty basic but useful.

Comment: I've chosen your answer over my own. It is closer to the spirit of the original inquiry as it is much easier to digest. TY for your input.

Comment: Only too glad to have been of help. Best - Geoff

Answer (score 0):

There is a Kant scholar that writes on Quora, but his writings aren't all about  the *Prolegomena*:--

- (https://www.quora.com/What-advice-would-people-who-study-Kant-and-Hegel-give-to-their-18-year-old-self-who-has-just-started-studying-Kant-and-Hegel/answer/Toni-Kannisto)
- (https://www.quora.com/I-am-1-3rd-through-Kant%E2%80%99s-Prolegomena-Is-this-a-good-place-to-start-with-Kant-Should-I-discard-this-attempt-and-read-the-Critique-instead/answer/Toni-Kannisto)
- (https://kannisto-kant.quora.com/)

You can verify the gentleman's credentials here, if you are skeptical:--

- (http://www.hf.uio.no/ifikk/english/people/aca/philosophy/temporary/tonik/)
- (https://no.linkedin.com/in/toni-kannisto-1aa480a) (This webpage is in Norwegian and possibly overlaps with other mutually intelligible Scandinavian language[s])